# третий параметр алгоритма find

Tags: c++

Используя метод find, легко найти есть ли заданное значение в контейнере, или нет:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::vector<int>::iterator itr = find(vec.begin() ,vec.end(), int val);
if(...)
```

и так далее;

Но что, если вектор содержит какие-либо структуры, объекты, или даже указатели на них? Возможно ли использовать эту функцию для нахождения необходимого значения, если оно является полем класса, а вектор состоит из указателей на объект этого класса? Что-то вроде:

```
class ClassName {
public:
int x;
std::string y;
};


std::string foo = "bar";
std::vector<ClassName*> vec1;
std::vector<ClassName*>::iterator itr = find( vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), ??? )
```

Что нужно написать вместо знаков вопроса, чтобы найти такой указатель, который указывает на объект, поле std::string y которого равно строке foo ?  Если это невозможно с алгоритмом find, то какие альтернативы?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте `find_if`, она принимает предикат.

```
std::string foo = "bar";
std::vector<ClassName*> vec1;
auto itr = std::find_if(begin(vec1), end(vec1), [&](ClassName* el){ return el->y == foo; });
```

Comment: Предикаты, лямбды и функторы - есть какая книга, рассматривающая такие вещи? el.y - у меня за ошибку считал в Visual studio, после изменения на el->y - он угомонился.

Comment: @derzz, лямбды - любая книга с покрытием C++11, предикаты и функторы (в программировании, предикат частный случай функтора, а лямбда весьма удобный сахар по созданию функторов) - любая книга, которая покрывает C++98/C++03 и новее. Либо: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82#C.2B.2B

Comment: @derzz Если именно книгу - то рекомендую Николаи Джосаттиса, "Стандартная библиотека С++"

Answer (score 2):

Если вам необходимо сравнить 2 объекта структуры/класса (а `find` именно этим и занимается, т.е. сравнивает на равенство), то объект должен реализовывать `bool operator ==`.
Для указателей же, @Abyx указал способ решения проблемы (да и не только для указателей).

---

P.S. Если же вы захотите использовать объекты данной структуры/класса в *упорядоченных ассоциативных контейнерах* (`std::map` и `std::set`) в качестве ключа, то структура/класс обязана реализовывать `bool operator <`, а остальные операторы сравнения могут быть выражены через него, а в *неупорядоченных ассоциативных контейнерах* необходимо реализовать `bool operator ==` и специализацию `std::hash`.

Comment: `operator<` нужен для элементов в ассоциативных *упорядоченных* контейнерах (типа `std::map`, `std::set`), а в *неупорядоченных* надо иметь `operator==` и специализацию `std::hash`.

Comment: @elexolut Согласен, почему-то я считал это очевидным (тот факт, что я говорю именно об упорядоченных ассоциативных контейнерах, ведь я упомянул словосочетание _в качестве ключа_) и не придал этому значения, но сейчас подправлю, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение будущих читателей. Спасибо за замечание :)